# Как правильно изменить регулярное выражение?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, str-replace

У меня есть строка типа:

```
((12846.05,14436.8001),(12852.4691,14431.2328),(12870.7499,14456.8501),(12835.8327,14443.7603),(12845.25,14435.8501),(12846.05,14436.8001))
```

Мне надо удалить все запятые между координатами, чтобы строка была вида:

```
((12846.0499999999993 14436.8001000000004,12852.4691000000003 14431.2327999999998,12870.7499000000007 14456.8500999999997,12835.8327000000008 14443.7602999999999,12845.25 14435.8500999999997,12846.0499999999993 14436.8001000000004))
```

Я написал регулярное выражение:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d),(?=\\d)", " ");
```

Но при отрицательных числах это не работает.
Как надо изменить регулярное выражение?

Comment: `"(?<=\\d),(?=-?\\d)"`

Comment: [Ещё как работает](https://regex101.com/r/zyEhM9/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Кстати, не только это нужно удалить. Ему необходимо удалить еще и скобки(кроме начала и конца)

Comment: Да, есть разница между требованием (*Мне надо удалить все запятые между координатами*) и желаемым результатом. Так что вопрос неясен.

Comment: да, в идеале, действительно, все хотелось бы привести к виду типа: `((7380.35599999999977 14638.5900099999999,7386.89000000000033 14410.6849899999997,7581.02900000000045 14421.4989999999998))`

Comment: Пробуйте https://regex101.com/

Comment: You can't do it with simple string regex/replacement pattern. You may though use `s.replaceAll("(?<=\\d),(?=-?\\d)", " ").replace("),(", ",")`